# JAVA - Why JNativeHook doesn't work on Windows?

Tags: java, windows, intellij-idea, keylogger, jnativehook

I am creating a simple key logger in JAVA so I use JNativeHook library to record keys typed.
My program works properly on Ubuntu but when I try to start it on Windows, the following error appears :

```
avr. 20, 2020 1:42:17 PM org.jnativehook.GlobalScreen$NativeHookThread enable
SEVERE: refresh_locale_list [628]: Could not find keyboard map for locale 0X00000000040C040C!
```

Do you know how to fix this bug ? (I use an AZERTY keyboard to test my code, the JAVA version of my project is 11.0.2 and I have the version 2.1.0  of JNativeHook)

Thanks for your answers.